# Split a JSON file to two different XML files

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I'm trying to split a JSON file to two different XML files. Example below.
Trying to use a python script to perform this. A groovy script would work as well. This split function is part of a file transformation in Apace NiFi.

JSON file :

```
{
    "Cars": {
        "Car": [{
                "Brand": "Volkswagon"
                "Country": "Germany",
                "Type": "All",
                "Models":
                [{
                        "Polo": {
                            "Type": "Hatchback",
                            "Color": "White",
                            "Cost": "10000"
                        }
                    } {
                        "Golf": {
                            "Type": "Hatchback",
                            "Color": "White",
                            "Cost": "12000"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Split to two XML files :

XML 1 :

```
<VehicleEntity>
    <VehicleEntity>
        <GlobalBrandId>Car123</GlobalBrandId>
        <Name>Random Value</Name>
        <Brand>Volkswagon</Brand>
    </VehicleEntity>
</VehicleEntity>
```

XML 2 :

```
<VehicleEntityDetail>
    <VehicleEntityDetailsEntity>
        <GlobalBrandId>Car123</GlobalBrandId>
        <Brand>Volkswagon</Brand>
        <Type>Hatchback</Type>
        <Color>White</Color>
        <Cost>10000</Cost>
    </VehicleEntityDetailsEntity>
</VehicleEntityDetail>
```

The XML tag names are a little different to the elements in the JSON file.
I'm looking for the best possible way to achieve this, but prefer a python script due to some experience working with Python.
Any other solution for Apache NiFi is also appreciated.

Comment: Should you write something yourself first...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Json to XML properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931787/convert-json-to-xml-properly)

Comment: @Ferris Will give it a try and feedback soon. Thanks!